# Open images sorted by name - PIL - Image.open()

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I inform a directory to my code and it has to open all the images in this directory, for example:

```
1-11.jpg
2-11.jpg
3-11.jpg
4-11.jpg
...
10-11.jpg
11-11.jpg
...
```

It opens all the files, however I need it to open the sorted files by name what does not currently happen ... how can I do this?

My code:

```
def convert_to_gray_scale(path, grayfilename):
    global image

    image = Image.open(path)

    # Converts the color image to grayscale
    image = image.convert("L")

    image.save(grayfilename)

directory = raw_input('\nEnter the directory of the image database: ')

# Creates the directory to store grayscale images
os.mkdir('GrayImages')

# Call the functions
for fn in glob.glob('*.jpg'):
    print '\nImage:',fn

    # Gets the file name without the extension
    f = glob.os.path.splitext(fn)[0]

    # Converts images in grayscale and saves them in GrayImages directory
    convert_to_gray_scale(fn, 'GrayImages/' + f + '_gray.jpg')
```

Comment: How are you doing it now? Maybe then we can suggest where to add a sorting function.

Comment: I updated the question, take a look...

Comment: try `for fn in sorted(glob.glob('*.jpg')):` and tell us if that's adequate. Although since your code isn't using `directory` I suspect you have other problems.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a very simple solution.

```
import os
for i in range(1, 12):
    os.system("start {}-11.jpg".format(i))
```

Comment: I need something more generic, because not always the name of the files will be like this...

Comment: @QuestionsOverflow Well, you have to decide if numbers should be put first in the queue  of opening or letters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a list, just sort it before opening the files with:
list.sort() or sorted(list)

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

```
def numeric_comparison(x, y):
    return int(x.split('-')[0]) - int(y.split('-')[0])

def convert_to_gray_scale(path, grayfilename):
    global image

    image = Image.open(path)

    # Converts the color image to grayscale
    image = image.convert("L")

    image.save(grayfilename)

directory = raw_input('\nEnter the directory of the image database: ')

# Creates the directory to store grayscale images
os.mkdir('GrayImages')

# Get the jpg files then sort them
sorted_files = sorted(glob.glob('*.jpg'), cmp=numeric_comparison)

# Call the functions
for fn in sorted_files:
    print '\nImage:',fn

    # Gets the file name without the extension
    f = glob.os.path.splitext(fn)[0]

    # Converts images in grayscale and saves them in GrayImages directory
    convert_to_gray_scale(fn, 'GrayImages/' + f + '_gray.jpg')
```

Comment: The reason it was doing that is because those are text files, so 1-11, 10-11 is the proper sort for a string. I updated the answer to include a numeric_sort that ASSUMES that all files are named with a numeric value for the first portion of the string followed by a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

As long as all the images you want to order are in the same directory, you can simply do the following:

```
import os, sys

path_sorted = sorted(os.listdir(path))
```

Comment: If the answer solves your problem or you believe it is the best solution. Please, up-vote and mark this answer as accepted! Thank you! If it doesn't solve your problem, let me know!